# SVG circle element shows "Invalid value" in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: css, svg

I have a `<circle>` element in a `<svg>` tag that displays fine in Chrome, but doesn't appear in Firefox. In fact, Firefox shows "Invalid value" where Chrome doesn't.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome works]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox doesn't work]

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnarjffm/) that demonstrates the same issue. Appears in Chrome, doesn't in Firefox.

How can I get this to work in FF? I need to use CSS since I'm relying on CSS media queries to change the radius of the circle.

Comment: If you want to use CSS for SVG attributes in Firefox, download its source code and implement support for that part of the SVG 2 specification. The SVG 2 specification is a work in progress and so is UAs support for it. Firefox and Chrome have implemented different parts of it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for your reply. It looks like styling SVG with CSS is part of the SVG 1.1 spec, however: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS

Comment: That's CSS properties you're talking about such as fill and stroke. r in SVG 1.1. is an attribute and attributes are not CSS stylable. In SVG 2 it's proposed that most attributes become CSS properties. There's no r in the https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html list

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I guess that answers my question!

Comment: Guess you'd be using `$('.focus circle').attr('r', XX);` in 2016. Have to check back in 2017 :--)

Comment: Two years later, 2018 and not 2017 - and firefox still doesn't support that :(